# What is the difference between array_udiff_assoc() and array_diff_uassoc()?

Tags: php, arrays, associative, custom-function, array-difference

What is the difference between `array_udiff_assoc()` and `array_diff_uassoc()`?

For `array_udiff_assoc()`, I have this code:

```
function myfunction($v1,$v2)
{
    if ($v1===$v2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
 
$a1 = ["a" => "Cat", "b" => "Dog", "c" => "Horse"];
$a2 = ["a" => "Cat", "b" => "Horse", "c" => "Dog"];
print_r(array_udiff_assoc($a1, $a2, "myfunction"));
```

result

```
Array ( [b] Dog [c] => Horse )
```

also `array_diff_uassoc()`:

```
function myfunction($v1,$v2)
{
    if ($v1===$v2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
     
$a1 = ["a" => "Cat", "b" => "Dog", ​"c" => "Horse"];
​$a2 = ["a" => "Cat", "b" => "Horse", "c" => "Dog"];
​print_r(array_diff_uassoc($a1, $a2, "myfunction"));
```

The result is same as first one:

```
Array ( [b] Dog [c] => Horse )
```

If they have any difference, what is it? The PHP manual does not says that they are aliases of each other.

Comment: You might also add `array_diff_assoc` and `array_udiff_uassoc` to the comparison...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a battery of test cases will clear up any confusion between these related native functions. I'll consistently use the native case-insensitive comparison function `strcasecmp()` to simplify the demonstration/explanation.

Here is the plain English explanation of how each function will behave:

1. [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) - case-sensitive value-only comparisons
2. [`array_diff_key()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) - case-sensitive key-only comparisons
3. [`array_diff_ukey()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-ukey.php) - case-insensitive key-only comparisons
4. [`array_diff_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) - case-sensitive key and case-sensitive value comparisons
5. [`array_diff_uassoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php) - * **first-occurring** case-insensitive key and case-sensitive value comparisons
6. [`array_udiff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) - case-insensitive value-only comparisons
7. [`array_udiff_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff-assoc.php) - case-sensitive key and case-insensitive value comparisons
8. [`array_udiff_uassoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff-uassoc.php) - case-insensitive key and case-insensitive value comparisons

*Pay very close attention to how 5. `array_diff_uassoc()` behaves differently with respect to the `['c' => 'd']` and `['m' => 'n']` comparisons due to the order of qualifying occurences in the `$second` array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JLoHG))

```
$first = [
    'A' => 'B',
    'c' => 'd',
    'E' => 'f',
    'g' => 'I',
    'k' => 'F',
    'm' => 'n',
    'o' => 'p',
];

$second = [
    'a' => 'b',
    'A' => 'b',
    'C' => 'd',
    'c' => 'D',
    'e' => 'F',
    'G' => 'H',
    'i' => 'B',
    'J' => 'D',
    'm' => 'N',
    'M' => 'n',
    'O' => 'r',
];

echo "array_diff()\n";
var_export(array_diff($first, $second));
echo "\n---\narray_diff_key()\n";
var_export(array_diff_key($first, $second));
echo "\n---\narray_diff_ukey()\n";
var_export(array_diff_ukey($first, $second, 'strcasecmp'));
echo "\n---\narray_diff_assoc()\n";
var_export(array_diff_assoc($first, $second));
echo "\n---\narray_diff_uassoc()\n";
var_export(array_diff_uassoc($first, $second, 'strcasecmp'));
echo "\n---\narray_udiff()\n";
var_export(array_udiff($first, $second, 'strcasecmp'));
echo "\n---\narray_udiff_assoc()\n";
var_export(array_udiff_assoc($first, $second, 'strcasecmp'));
echo "\n---\narray_udiff_uassoc()\n";
var_export(array_udiff_uassoc($first, $second, 'strcasecmp', 'strcasecmp'));
```

Output:

```
array_diff()
array (
  'E' => 'f',
  'G' => 'I',
  'o' => 'p',
)
---
array_diff_key()
array (
  'E' => 'f',
  'k' => 'F',
  'o' => 'p',
)
---
array_diff_ukey()
array (
  'k' => 'F',
)
---
array_diff_assoc()
array (
  'A' => 'B',
  'c' => 'd',
  'E' => 'f',
  'G' => 'I',
  'k' => 'F',
  'm' => 'n',
  'o' => 'p',
)
---
array_diff_uassoc()
array (
  'A' => 'B',
  'E' => 'f',
  'G' => 'I',
  'k' => 'F',
  'm' => 'n',
  'o' => 'p',
)
---
array_udiff()
array (
  'G' => 'I',
  'o' => 'p',
)
---
array_udiff_assoc()
array (
  'E' => 'f',
  'G' => 'I',
  'k' => 'F',
  'o' => 'p',
)
---
array_udiff_uassoc()
array (
  'G' => 'I',
  'k' => 'F',
  'o' => 'p',
)
```

Answer (score 6):

They both do the same, but `udiff-assoc` compares the DATA with the user supplied function, while `diff-uassoc` compares the INDEX with the user supplied function.

As an answer to @lonsesomeday : as indicated by the 'u', `diff_assoc` will use internal functions for all comparisons, and `udiff_uassoc` uses provided callbacks for index and data comparison.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

> [`array_udiff_assoc`](http://php.net/array_udiff_assoc) — Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check, compares data by a callback function
>   [`array_diff_uassoc`](http://php.net/array_diff_uassoc) — Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check which is performed by a user supplied callback function

So, the function differ in the place where they use the callback function. udiff_assoc uses the callback to compare elements, diff_uassoc uses the callback when comparing the indices.