# Get the difference between two 2-dimensional arrays (each containing a single column of values)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, associative-array, array-difference

I have an array containing rows of associative data.

```
$array1 = array(
    array('ITEM' => 1),
    array('ITEM' => 2),
    array('ITEM' => 3),
);
```

I have a second array, also containing rows of associative data, that I would like to filter using the first array.

```
$array2 = array(
    array('ITEM' => 2),
    array('ITEM' => 3),
    array('ITEM' => 1),
    array('ITEM' => 4),
);
```

This feels like a job for `array_diff()`, but how can I compare the rows exclusively on the deeper `ITEM` values?

How can I filter the second array and get the following result?

```
array(3 => array('ITEM' => 4))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would probably iterate through the original arrays and make them 1-dimensional... something like

```
foreach($array1 as $aV){
    $aTmp1[] = $aV['ITEM'];
}

foreach($array2 as $aV){
    $aTmp2[] = $aV['ITEM'];
}

$new_array = array_diff($aTmp1,$aTmp2);
```

Answer (score 67):

You can define a custom comparison function using [`array_udiff()`](http://php.net/array_udiff).

```
function udiffCompare($a, $b)
{
    return $a['ITEM'] - $b['ITEM'];
}

$arrdiff = array_udiff($arr2, $arr1, 'udiffCompare');
print_r($arrdiff);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ITEM] => 4
        )
)
```

This uses and preserves the arrays' existing structure, which I assume you want.

Comment: I know this is a bit old topic, but for others that use ids that are not integers but strings, you might want to use  return strcmp($a['ITEM],$b['ITEM']) in the udiffCompare function

Comment: In PHP7 and beyond, you can use the [spaceship operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator): `return $a['ITEM'] <=> $b['ITEM'];`

Comment: One thing I wish I had known before trying to use this function is that the `array_udiff` function arguments `$arr2` and `$arr1` do NOT correlate to the function arguments `$a` and `$b` of `udiffCompare`. I kept scratching my head wondering why elements of `$arr2` were being compared against itself inside of the callback. I found that out with this comment in the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php#80149

Answer (score 20):

Another fun approach with a `json_encode` trick (can be useful if you need to "raw" compare some complex values in the first level array) :

```
// Compare all values by a json_encode
$diff = array_diff(array_map('json_encode', $array1), array_map('json_encode', $array2));

// Json decode the result
$diff = array_map('json_decode', $diff);
```

Comment: Thanks, only this works. symmetrical version       `public static function myArrayDiff($array1, $array2)
    {
        return array_map('json_decode', array_merge(
            array_diff(array_map('json_encode', $array1), array_map('json_encode', $array2)),
            array_diff(array_map('json_encode', $array2), array_map('json_encode', $array1))
        ));
    }`

Comment: This answer is working much harder than it needs to.  Mutating the input with json encoding is not necessary.  `array_udiff()` is the most suitable tool for this task.

Answer (score 8):

A couple of solutions using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) that are less performant than [the `array_udiff` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11822305/1709587) for large arrays, but which are a little more straightforward and more flexible:

```
$array1 = [
    ['ITEM' => 1],
    ['ITEM' => 2],
    ['ITEM' => 3],
];

$array2 = [
    ['ITEM' => 2],
    ['ITEM' => 3],
    ['ITEM' => 1],
    ['ITEM' => 4],
];

$arrayDiff = array_filter($array2, function ($element) use ($array1) {
    return !in_array($element, $array1);
});

// OR

$arrayDiff = array_filter($array2, function ($array2Element) use ($array1) {
    foreach ($array1 as $array1Element) {
        if ($array1Element['ITEM'] == $array2Element['ITEM']) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

As always with `array_filter`, note that `array_filter` preserves the keys of the original array, so if you want `$arrayDiff` to be zero-indexed, do `$arrayDiff = array_values($arrayDiff);` after the `array_filter` call.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code to get difference.

```
array_diff(array_column($a1, 'ITEM'), array_column($a2, 'ITEM'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Trust that the maintainers of PHP have optimized [`array_udiff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) to outperform all other techniques which could do the same.

With respect to your scenario, you are seeking a filtering `array_diff()` that evaluates data within the first level's "value" (the row of data).  Within the custom function, the specific column must be isolated for comparison.  For a list of all native `array_diff()` function variations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817582/2943403).

To use the first array to filter the second array (and output the retained data from the second array), you must write `$array2` as the first parameter and `$array1` as the second parameter.

`array_diff()` and `array_intersect()` functions that leverage (contain `u` in their function name) expect an integer as their return value.  [That value is used to preliminary sort the data before actually performing the evaluations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php#119657) -- this is a performance optimization.  There may be scenarios where if you only return `0` or `1` (not a three-way comparison), then the results may be unexpected.  To ensure a stable result, always provide a comparison function that can return a negative, a positive, and a zero integer.

When comparing integer values, subtraction (`$a - $b`) will give reliable return values.  For greater utility when comparing float values or non-numeric data, you can use the spaceship operator when your PHP version makes it available.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F6jo5))

- #### PHP7.4+ (arrow functions)

  ```
  var_export(
      array_udiff($array2, $array1, fn($a, $b) => $a['ITEM'] <=> $b['ITEM'])
  );
  ```
- #### PHP7+ (spaceship operator)

  ```
  var_export(
      array_udiff(
          $array2,
          $array1,
          function($a, $b) {
              return $a['ITEM'] <=> $b['ITEM'];
          }
      )
  );
  ```
- #### PHP5.3+ (anonymous functions)

  ```
  var_export(
      array_udiff(
          $array2,
          $array1,
          function($a, $b) {
              return $a['ITEM'] === $b['ITEM']
                  ? 0
                  : ($a['ITEM'] > $b['ITEM'] ? 1 : -1);
          }
      )
  );
  ```

Output for all version above:

```
array (
  3 => 
  array (
    'ITEM' => 4,
  ),
)
```

When working with object arrays, the technique is the same; only the syntax to access a property is different from accessing an array element (`$a['ITEM']` would be `$a->ITEM`).

---

For scenarios where the element being isolated from one array does not exist in the other array, you will need to coalesce both `$a` and `$b` data to the opposite fallback column because the data from the first array and the second arrays will be represented in both arguments of the callback.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GIX20))

```
$array1 = array(
    array('ITEM' => 1),
    array('ITEM' => 2),
    array('ITEM' => 3),
);

$array2 = array(
    array('ITEMID' => 2),
    array('ITEMID' => 3),
    array('ITEMID' => 1),
    array('ITEMID' => 4),
);

// PHP7.4+ (arrow functions)
var_export(
    array_udiff(
        $array2,
        $array1,
        fn($a, $b) => ($a['ITEM'] ?? $a['ITEMID']) <=> ($b['ITEM'] ?? $b['ITEMID'])
    )
);
```

Or because only the first column values from both data sets are being compared:

```
var_export(
    array_udiff($array2, $array1, fn($a, $b) => current($a) <=> current($b))
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Having the same problem but my multidimensional array has various keys unlike your "ITEM" consistently in every array.

Solved it with: `$result = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);`

Reference: [PHP: array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: This does not work on multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution
if( json_encode($array1) == json_encode($array2) ){
...
}

Answer (score -2):

Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

```
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```