# Speed up array comparison

Tags: php

I have two multidimensional arrays, both with email address data, but different keys, that I'm trying to compare. I need to get all of the email addresses that don't exist in both arrays, and store them. Is there a way I can speed this up?

$accts: id, Email, column1 - 13000 rows

$db_accts: id1, name, accountID,Email_Address__c - 17000 rows

Right now I have

```
foreach($accts as $acct){
    $exists = false;
    foreach($db_accts as $db_acct){
        if($acct['Email'] == $db_acct['Email_Address__c'])
        {   $exists = true;}
    }

    if(!$exists)
    {   $update[] = array('Email'=>$acct['Email'],'column1'=>'');
    }

}

foreach($db_accts as $db_acct){
    $exists = false;
    foreach($accts as $acct){
        if($acct['Email'] == $db_acct['Email_Address__c'])
            $exists = true; 
    }
    if(!$exists)
    {
        $update[] = array('Email'=>$db_acct['Email_Address__c'],'column1'=>'Y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. One is from a local DB, one from a remote server. SQL queries won't help me unless I load up a temporary table.

Comment: well if the end destination is a db, it still may be best handled with (my)sql

Comment: It's actually going into a 3rd db. I'm comparing data from company1 to my data, then uploading it to company2. Data from both companies is accessed via SOAP/REST.

Comment: well you can just inset one lot in to the db, then the other, with email address as a unique key, the db will take care of duplicates.

Comment: That would only load all of the email address in the database. It wouldn't tell me which addresses don't exist in both.

Comment: on each insert you check, if it was rejected as a duplicate, so you can get a list of which where duplicates, and which where not.

Answer (score 1):

#### By hand

Algorithmically, what you are doing is `O(|accts| * |db_accts|)`.

You could sort both accounts by email, which requires `O(|accts| * log(|accts|)) + O(|db_accts| * log(|db_accts|))`. Then, you could

1. start with the first element of both,
2. compare
3. if the element of `accts` is bigger, store it and iterate to the next element in `accts`
4. likewise if the element of `db_accts` is bigger
5. if both are the same, iterate both without storing.
6. goto 3. if there are still elements

The comparison should take `O(|accts| + |db_accts|)`. If you get them sorted by email from the DBs, that would omit the sort-step above. Otherwise, it is `O(n log(n))`, which is way smaller than `O(n^2)`.

This should result in a speedup of about 1000 in your dataset (`log(17000) vs 13000`).

For sorting in PHP, have a look at [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value).

For SQL, see [MySQL "Group By" and "Order By"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by).

#### By PHP

You can use [array_diff() with multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably speed this up using array_diff: http://de3.php.net/array_diff

Comment: I don't see anything about multidimensional arrays with different keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/array_diff).

See the documentation, the example is really quite clear. You input two arrays and `array_diff()` spits out the ones that are different. In your case emails that are not contained in both arrays.

Comment: I don't see anything about multidimensional arrays with different keys.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own PHP code is much slower than using a standard PHP function. The standard functions of PHP run on a lower level and therefore have less overhead. Using a function such as [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) will be much more efficient.

Comment: While this won't work with the arrays as I have them (I don't see anything about multidimensional arrays, comparing on different keys, etc), I suppose I can create new arrays with just the email addresses and compare those instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array_udiff` as it allows you to customize the comparison:

```
array_udiff($accts,$db_accts,function($act,$dbact){
     return strcasecmp($act['Email'], $db_act['Email_Address__c']);
 });
```