# array_diff() based on one column between two arrays with associative rows

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, associative-array, array-difference

I have two multidimensional arrays which are indexed arrays of associative rows.

```
$array1 = array(
    array('name' => 'foo', 'id' => 12),
    array('name' => 'bar', 'id' => 34),
    array('name' => 'boo', 'id' => 56),
);

$array2 = array(
    array('name' => 'bar', 'id' => 34),
    array('name' => 'boo', 'id' => 56),
    array('name' => 'bar', 'id' => 78),
);
```

It is possible that rows might have different `id` values but the same `name` value -- such as `bar` in my sample input data.

I need to compare the arrays based on `id` values only.

Expected Output: (because `id`s `34` and `56` are found in `$array2`)

```
array(
    array('name' => 'foo', 'id' => 12)
)
```

I tried `$one_not_two = array_diff($array1['id'], $array2['id']);` which does not return anything.

I also tried `$one_not_two = array_diff($array1['id'], $array2['id']);`
which returned an error "argument is not an array."

Originally, I got around it by extracting the `id`s into a one-dimensional array, then just comparing those.  Now a new feature in our application requires me to compare the rows while maintaining the multidimensional structure. Any advice?

Our servers are currently running php 5.3 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the arrays are multidimensional you have to extract the ids like this:

```
$ids1 = array();
foreach($array1 as $elem1)
    $ids1[] = $elem1['id'];

$ids2 = array();
foreach($array2 as $elem2)
    $ids2[] = $elem2['id'];

$one_not_two = array_diff($ids1,$ids2);
```

For your specific question, check out [array_diff() with multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: Thanks but I mentioned in my question that I tried something similar already. That would be an easy solution but something in the rest of the script requires $one_not_two to contain the mapping name => id.

Comment: Then you should look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Added your comment to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_udiff](http://www.php.net/array_udiff) to create a custom diff function:

```
$diff = array_udiff($array1,
                    $array2,
                    function ($a, $b){
                        if($a['id'] == $b['id']){
                            return 0;
                        } else {
                            return ($a['id'] < $b['id'] ? -1 : 1);
                        }
                    }
                );
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/2u5EWg

Answer (score 0):

If id is unique you can do that:

```
$one_not_two = array();

foreach ($array1 as $val) {
    $one_not_two[$val['id']] = $val;
}

foreach ($array1 as $val) {
    if (!isset($one_not_two[$val['id']])) {
        $one_not_two[$val['id']] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it by changing Array1 to an associative array of `name => id`

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem as you.

Solved it with: `$result = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);`

Reference: [PHP: array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)