# Split flat array into two arrays based on value

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I have a PHP array that I am trying to split into 2 different arrays.  I am trying to pull out any values that contain the word "hidden".  So one array would contain all the values that do not contain the word "hidden".  The other array would contain all the values that do contain the word "hidden".  I just can't figure out how to  do it though.

The original array is coming from a form post that contains keys and values from a bunch of check boxes and hidden inputs.  so the actual post value looks something like this:

```
Group1 => Array([0] => item1,[1] => item2hidden,[2] => item3,[3] => item4,[4] => item5hidden)
```

so to simplify it:

```
$myArray = Array(item1, item2hidden, item3, item4, item5hidden)
```

final output

```
$arr1 = (item1, item3, item4)
$arr2 = (item2hidden, item5hidden)
```

Anyone know how to do something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$myArray = array('item1', 'item2hidden', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5hidden');
$secondaryArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, "hidden") !== false) {
        $secondaryArray[] = $value;
        unset($myArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

It moves all the entries that contain "hidden" from the `$myArray` to `$secondaryArray`.

**Note:** It's case sensitive

Answer (score 30):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

```php
$myArray = array('item1', 'item2hidden', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5hidden');

$arr1 = array_filter($myArray, function($v) { return strpos($v, 'hidden') === false; });
$arr2 = array_diff($myArray, $arr1);
```

Comment: Need to be `=== false;` instead of `== false;`

Comment: Doesn't work if you have array values inside your initial array. For instance, $myArray = [['id' => 1], ['id'] => 2];

Comment: @andnik: just replace `strpos($v, ...`to `strpos($v['id'], ...`

Comment: @Glavić, thanks, but I'm referring to second part. array_diff doesn't work when you are using multidimensional array. This link seems to contain answer I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = Array('item1', 'item2hidden', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5hidden');
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();    
foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    if (strpos($item, "hidden") !== false) {
        $arr1[] = $item;
    } else {
        $arr2[] = $item;
    }
}
```

This solution checks if 'hidden' present at current item, if no, move to `$arr1` else to `$arr2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter:

```
function filtreHiddens($e) {
    if (isset($e['hidden']) && $e['hidden']) return true;
    else return false;
}

function filtreNotHiddens($e) {
    if (isset($e['hidden']) && !$e['hidden']) return true;
    else return false;
}

$arrayToFiltre = array(
    array('hidden' => true, 'someKey' => 'someVal'),
    array('hidden' => false, 'someKey1' => 'someVal1'),
    array('hidden' => true, 'someKey2' => 'someVal3'),
);

$hidden = array_filter($arrayToFiltre, 'filtreHiddens');
$notHidden = array_filter($arrayToFiltre, 'filtreNotHiddens');

print_r($hidden);
print_r($notHidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just me, but I would go for the clarity of regular expressions...

```
foreach($myArray as $item) {
    if (preg_match("/hidden$/i", $item)) {
        array_push($arr2, $item);
    } else {
        array_push($arr1, $item);
    }
}
```