# php split array on change of value in column data

Tags: php, arrays, split

I am trying to split array data into multiple arrays based on change in data value at known position (column).

```
$input =  array(
  array(1,2,3),
  array(4,5,3),
  array(7,8,4),
  array(9,10,4),
  array(11,12,4)
);
```

Here column 3 changes values from 3 to 4
and expected result is to have 2 arrays

```
$out1 = array(array(1,2,3),array(4,5,3));
$out2 = array(array(7,8,4), array(9,10,4), array(11,12,4));
```

since number of rows are variable, cannot use array_chunk
since column 3 values are variable, cannot use array_filter
number of output arrays are also variable.
trying splice but failing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP splitting array into two arrays based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098268/php-splitting-array-into-two-arrays-based-on-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_reduce to make new array, where index will be equal to last numbers in items

```
$new = array_reduce($input, function($c, $x) {  $c[$x[2]][] = $x; return $c; }, [] );
$out1 = $new[3];
$out2 = $new[4];
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea703fda20b319af87b19017637a2afb53df0ebd)

But if array is not sorted and you want to split at points of changing that number, the code can be

```
$i = -1;
$last = null;
$new = [];
foreach($input as $x) {
    if ($x[2] != $last) {
        $i++;
        $last = $x[2];
    }
    $new[$i][] = $x;
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfe26a5f3a0ce193745693be178e8d1b43843f61)

Comment: Yes this works for the regular array as in the question.
but not for an array with key=>values like
     $a =  array(
     array('k1'=>1,'k2'=>2,'k3'=>3),
     array('k1'=>4,'k2'=>5,'k3'=>3),
     array('k1'=>7,'k2'=>8,'k3'=>4),
     array('k1'=>9,'k2'=>10,'k3'=>4)
     );
where i get Undefined offset: 2
could you clarify

Comment: Change $x2 with end($x)

Comment: {  $c[end($x)] = $x; return $c; }
outputs only the last arrays of each set. demo at . 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fa0a51574a8106847f88ee5b0629d43c5050c92

Comment: You should add empty square brackets as in my code (i can't write it on this phone :))

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9fa14ae64f28cd8ad4fd809438b686ab863f48f

Answer (score 0):

You can use split index with index of array,

```
$out1 = $out2 = [];
$splitIndex = 2;
foreach($input as $k => $v){
    if($k < $splitIndex){
        $out1[] = $v;
    }else{
        $out2[] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($out1);
print_r($out2);
```

[Working demo](https://3v4l.org/pUTjo)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```