# PHP array_diff_assoc () compare multi-deminsions arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have 2 arrays to find difference

**Array1**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
```

**Array2**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I use [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/function.array-diff-assoc) function to get difference.

Problem:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion at array_diff_assoc()
```

Is there function that can compare arrays in arrays?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71049380/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column):

```
$array1 = array(
    array('id' => 1),
    array('id' => 2),
    array('id' => 3),
    array('id' => 4),
    array('id' => 5),
);
$array2 = array(
    array('user_id' => 1),
);

$diff = array_diff(array_column($array1, 'id'), array_column($array2, 'user_id'));

var_dump($diff);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should use `array_diff_key()` instead of `array_diff_assoc()` because `array_diff_assoc()` doesn't search recursively. It try to notify user that one of the values in array is also an array and it had to convert it to a string.