# Remove array from a multidimensional array if the same value exists in another multidimensional array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [controller] => users
            [action] => index
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [controller] => users
            [action] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [controller] => users
            [action] => login
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [controller] => users
            [action] => index
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [controller] => users
            [action] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [controller] => users
            [action] => logout
        )

)
```

I want to remove complete nested array from 1st array if a match is found in 2nd array (Based on keys ['controller'] &&['action']). So in the first array only the 3rd [2] array is unique.

**The output should be like :**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [controller] => users
                [action] => login
            )
    )
```

**Please Note**
Please note that the 2nd array doesn't necessary to be in same order as first. As opposed in my question where the first two arrays of each array are identical.

**What i have tried is :**

```
$result = array();

for($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++)
{
    $result[] = array_diff($a[$i], $b[$i]);
}

print_r($result); // This doesn't give required output. It removes every thing and return like 


Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [action] => login
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways you could go about this. Here's one that I think would be pretty simple.

First up, setup a new array based on `$a`, indexing it by the controller and action attributes.

```
$final = array();
foreach($a AS $item) {
    $final[$item['controller'] . $item['action']] = $item;
}
```

Now you can loop through the second array, removing any matching items.

```
foreach($b AS $item) {
    unset($final[$item['controller'] . $item['action']]);
}
```

Now `$final` should be the array you want.

Working example: http://3v4l.org/JtUkN

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays) answer. I think it'll do exactly what you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own working solution

```
for($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++)
    {
        foreach($this->existing_data as $v)
        {
            if( ($v['controller'] == $data[$i]['controller']) && ($v['action'] == $data[$i]['action']) )
            {
                unset($data[$i]);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```