# How to filter Associate Array based on Array index using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

There are two associative arrays which i need to compare. But both arrays have different number of index keys.

The first array is exclude array and second array has list of user ids. What i need to achieve is that i need to return only items having user_id that are not in array 1. I used array_diff_assoc() but returned wrong array.

Array 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 10080
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 10074
                )

        )

)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [mail_id] => 14
                    [user_id] => 10080
                    [error_status] => 0
                    [recipient_type] => I
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [mail_id] => 14
                    [user_id] => 10059
                    [error_status] => 0
                    [recipient_type] => I
                )

        )

)
```

$result = array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2);

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 10080
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I kinda get what you want, but if you can explain why you are doing this we might be able to advise better. Do you really need to make a second array of data from one you already have? consider the overhead used to search and create a new array might match or be more than just accessing the one array with all data. Also, have you looked at all the array function options on php.net? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: I just need to filter array2 based on array 1 using index "user_id"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11822305/4609548) and modified for you using [arra_udiff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php).

```
function udiffCompare($a, $b)
{
    return $a['a']['user_id'] - $b['a']['user_id'];
}
$arrdiff = array_udiff($array2, $array1, 'udiffCompare');
print_r($arrdiff);
```

Comment: Hi, i tried  $mail_recipients = array_udiff($mail_recipients, $mail_exclude_recipients,function($a,$b){
                    return $a['a']['user_id'] - $b['a']['user_id'];
                }); but not working

Comment: yup it worked when custom function is written as separate function i tried to write it as inline.... thanks man!