# How can I detect the differences between two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, I would like to compare.

array1:

```
array(4) {
  ["123"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(2) "cat"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "fred"
  }
  ["345"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(3) "dog"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "alan"
  }
  ["order"]=>
  string(2) "12"
}
```

array2:

```
   array(4) {
      ["123"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["animal"]=>
        string(2) "cat"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "fred"
      }
      ["345"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["animal"]=>
        string(3) "fox"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "tom"
      }
      ["order"]=>
      string(2) "12"
    }
```

I compare them with array_diff:

```
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

But if I var_dump $result, I get the following output:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: whats your desired output??

Comment: @sinaza: Thank you, that was a great help. I found out what was wrong and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For associative arrays you should use [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php). Also see the user contributed notes for how to do this recursively, if you need to.

Comment: I already tried this `$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);` but still I get the output `array(0) {
}`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of sinaza I found out that no difference was displayed, because `array_diff` works different with multidimensional arrays.

Here is the code, that worked for me:

```
foreach ($array1 as $k1 => $v1) {
   if (array_diff($array2[$k1], $array1[$k1])){
      $result[$k1] = array_diff($array2[$k1], $array1[$k1]);
   }
}
```