# PHP array How do i get only value one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have problem in multidimensional array
I have a PHP array as follows:

```
$array1 = array( 
1 => '01-Jul-2017',
2 => '02-Jul-2017',
3 => '03-Jul-2017',
4 => '04-Jul-2017',
5 => '05-Jul-2017',
...,
31 => '31-Jul-2017',);

$array2 = array( 
1 => '01-Jul-2017',
3 => '03-Jul-2017',
4 => '04-Jul-2017',
5 => '05-Jul-2017',
6 => '06-Jul-2017',
...,
30 => '31-Jul-2017');

foreach($array1 as $array_one) {
    foreach($array2 as $array_two) {
        if($array_one == $array_two) {
            echo 'write';
        } else {
            **I want to display that does not exist in $ array2 output 02-Jul-2017;**
        }
    }
}
```

**How do i get just the value 02-Jul-2017**

Comment: That's number 2 of `$array1`

Comment: Use array_diff() Please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: this is the question `I want to display that does not exist in $ array2` for that use `array_diff($array1, $array2)`

Comment: also these are not `multidimensional array`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array\_diff() with multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_diff()` inbuilt function.

```
$array1 = array( 
1 => '01-Jul-2017',
2 => '02-Jul-2017',
3 => '03-Jul-2017',
4 => '04-Jul-2017',
5 => '05-Jul-2017');

$array2 = array( 
1 => '01-Jul-2017',
3 => '03-Jul-2017',
4 => '04-Jul-2017',
5 => '05-Jul-2017',
6 => '06-Jul-2017');

$result=array_diff($array1,$array2);
print_r($result);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [2] => 02-Jul-2017 )
```

Let me know if it not works.