# Filter multidimensional php array with another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array `$result` as such:

```
[0] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [itemid] => 1
    [name] => A
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [itemid] => 2
    [name] => B
  )
)
[1] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [itemid] => 3
    [name] => C
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [itemid] => 2
    [name] => B
  )
)
```

and an array `$items` as such:

```
[0] => Array (
  [itemid] => 2
  [name] => B
)
[1] => Array (
  [itemid] => 4
  [name] => D
)
```

How do I remove all items from the `$result` array, that occur in the `$items` array? In this case, the `$result` would become:

```
[0] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [itemid] => 1
    [name] => A
  )
)
[1] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [itemid] => 3
    [name] => C
  )
)
```

Since the question is mostly code, here's some extra characters to make StackOverflow accept the question.

Comment: Sounds like a familiar problem to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821824/1502207

Comment: I'd say your question has no code at all, only variables and a wish. No attempt at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. (Not tested yet)

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $key => $array) {
    $result[$key] = array_diff($array, $items);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Code doesn't work but that definitely puts me on the right track.