# Array_diff in foreach?

Tags: php, loops, diff

I need to compare values from some arrays.
This array is multi dimensional and I need to compare the arrays inside.

**Here the dump:**

> php

```
    array (size=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '96' (length=2)
      1 => string '90' (length=2)
      2 => string '91' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '96' (length=2)
      1 => string '90' (length=2)
      2 => string '91' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '96' (length=2)
      1 => string '90' (length=2)
      2 => string '91' (length=2)
      3 => string '98' (length=2)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '96' (length=2)
      1 => string '90' (length=2)
      2 => string '91' (length=2)
      3 => string '98' (length=2)
```

I wanted to use something like `array_diff`, to compare the different arrays but... even if it seems stupid, I don't know how to do it.
I guess I expect to "extract" the 4 array, to be able to compare them.

Is there somebody that can explain me a good way to do this ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array\_diff() with multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @DrakulaPredatorم I expect to "extract" the 4 array, to be able to compare them

Comment: Agreed, but please update your question with expected output array.

Comment: What do you mean by `compare` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 as you can see in the dump, only the array 3 and the array 4 have the ligne "98". This is what I mean, telling like "ok, this array has this value and this array does not have it".

Comment: @Chris_1985 So, in other words, you want uncommon elements which are not present across all 4 arrays?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, we can see it like this

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = [
    ['96','90','91'],
    ['96','90','91'],
    ['96','90','91','98'],
    ['96','90','91','98'],
];

$set = [];

foreach ($arr as $values) {
    foreach($values as $each_value){
        if(!isset($set[$each_value])) $set[$each_value] = true;
    }
}

$result = [];

$set = array_keys($set);

foreach ($arr as $values) {
    foreach($set as $value){
        if(!in_array($value,$values)) $result[] = $value;
    }
}

$result = array_unique($result);

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/gMZUR

- We first make a set of elements to be present across each array.
- Later, we move across all arrays once again and check each element in the set against each array values.
- If we find an element in the set not present in any of the each individual sub arrays, we add it in the `result`.
- Note that we can count frequency of element and compare it with the size of the actual data set, but duplicate values could cause issues.