# How to find missing element of one array to another in php without using built in function?

Tags: php

I have two array as I mention below:

```
$arr1 = array("1","3","4","6");
$arr2 = array("2","3","4","5","7");
```

I want to get those elements that are not in `$arr2` without using built-in function. So, how can I do this?

Comment: why not array_diff?

Comment: I answered a **similar** question yesterday. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771451/array-diff-in-foreach/

Comment: *"without using built in function"* Do you specifically mean only PHP's array functions? Or all built-in functions?

Comment: I mean without any function like `array_diff(), unset(), array_splice()` any other function which is already define in php @JayBlanchard

Comment: @darkshadow There is no alternative for unset, you must use it.

Comment: Actually @DrakulaPredatorم, you don't have to use it, but it requires a lot more code. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop twice and unset if matches and break the inner loop

```
$arr1 = array("1","3","4","6");
$arr2 = array("2","3","4","5","7");

foreach($arr1 as $k => $v){
    foreach($arr2 as $k1 => $v1){
        if($v == $v1){
            unset($arr1[$k]);break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($arr1);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WMc9U).

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 6
)
```

Comment: The OP said "without using built-in function"

Comment: Yep - that is almost exactly what I would do. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was intrigued by the question of not using any of the array functions or specialty functions in PHP, so here is what I came up with to diff the two arrays (*as they are written, no further testing has been performed, it would likely break*) without using those functions. It requires some juggling:

```
$arr1 = array("1","3","4","6");
$arr2 = array("2","3","4","5","7");

$inTwo = array();
$notInTwo = array();

// get the matching elements from the two arrays to create a new array
foreach($arr1 AS $key => $val) {
    foreach($arr2 AS $key2 => $val2) {
        if($val == $val2) {
            $inTwo[] = $val2;
        }
    }
}

print_r($inTwo);
$match = NULL; // variable used to hold match values, so they can be skipped

foreach($arr1 AS $key3 => $val3) {
    foreach($inTwo AS $key4 => $val4) {
        echo $val3 . ' ' . $val4 . "\n";
        if(($val3 == $val4) || ($match == $val4)) { // test
            echo "match\n";
            $match = $val3; // set the new variable, to be checked on the next iteration
            echo $match ."\n";
            break;
        } else {
            $notInTwo[] = $val3;
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r($notInTwo);
```

Here is the output (all test output left in for reference):

```
Array //print_r($inTwo);
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
1 3
3 3
match // set the match variable
3
4 3 // skip this due to the match
match // set the match variable
4
6 3
Array print_r($notInTwo);
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6
)
```

[EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2df569827191b1ef898ea848d7982af74746063)

Diffing two arrays requires some recursion. If you want to know how this works under the hood you could look into the source for PHP (and other languages that offer a diffing algorithm) to get an idea of how to do this. What I've written here is crude, a bull-in-the-China-shop approach to the problem.

Comment: I ain't thought that way+1:):)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_walk` with `in_array`

```
$r = [];
array_walk($arr1, function($v, $k) use (&$r, $arr2){
  !in_array($v,$arr2) ? ($r[]=$v) : '';
});
```

Comment: The OP said "without built-in functions"