# Assoc array difference based on specific key value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. I want to get the difference between them based on the sub-key `name`. I can use `array_diff(array_column($array2, 'name'), array_column($array1, 'name'));` but then my resulting array lacks the other key/values `id` and `created` because of the usage of `array_column`. I don't require the top level numeric index to be the same as the wanted array.

I have collections installed but I wasn't able to find a suitable method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods

Array 1

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_02_67.zip',
    'id' => '/restore_point_backups/sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_02_67.zip',
    'created' => 1563787267,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_00_38.zip',
    'id' => '/restore_point_backups/sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_00_38.zip',
    'created' => 1563787197,
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_19_09_48_16.zip',
    'id' => '/restore_point_backups/sitebackup_2019_07_19_09_48_16.zip',
    'created' => 1563787125,
  ),
)
```

Array 2

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_19_08_52_37.zip',
    'created' => 1563519157,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_19_09_48_16.zip',
    'created' => 1563522496,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_00_38.zip',
    'created' => 1563696044,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_02_67.zip',
    'created' => 1563696184,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_12_29.zip',
    'created' => 1563696754,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_Jul_21_10_17_58.zip',
    'created' => 1563697083,
  ),
)
```

Wanted

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_19_08_52_37.zip',
    'created' => 1563519157,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_12_29.zip',
    'created' => 1563696754,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\\files',
    'name' => 'sitebackup_2019_Jul_21_10_17_58.zip',
    'created' => 1563697083,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Specifically my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71049380/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code. It will work.

```
  //Get the column value from array 2 by name
    $array2_col = array_column($array_2, 'name');
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
       //if array1 name value exist in array 2 get that key and delete from array 2 using unset.
          $index = array_search($value['name'],  $array2_col);
           if($index !== false ){
              unset($array_2[$index]);
           }
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array_2 );
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/12V0d)

Output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => C:\xampp\htdocs\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\files
            [name] => sitebackup_2019_07_19_08_52_37.zip
            [created] => 1563519157
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => C:\xampp\htdocs\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\files
            [name] => sitebackup_2019_07_21_10_12_29.zip
            [created] => 1563696754
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => C:\xampp\htdocs\restore_point_backups_fagardesignscom\files
            [name] => sitebackup_2019_Jul_21_10_17_58.zip
            [created] => 1563697083
        )

)
```

If you want to be an array index in sequence like 1,2,3, can use array_value.

```
print_r(array_values($array_2));
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/tlicM)

Comment: @alex, when you get a chance try the above solution, it will work as you wanted.

Comment: Glad to help you..:)

Comment: a problem appeared in testing as one of the items has a 0 for index. as array search returns the index `0` then `if ($key)` erroneously evaluated to false. i replaced `array_search` with `if (in_array($value['name'], $localFilesCol)) {`. i think it will probably perform faster anyways.

Comment: yes i think it will be good, or we can also update the condition like.   if($key !== false ){
    unset($array_2[$key]);
   }