# Show what's not in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array build. In this structure, I want to compare the array and list the ones that are not in the 1st array. I use **array_diff** but I get an error because it is a multi array. How should I do this with **Foreach**?

1. Array

```
{
    0: {
      0: "Mantar",
      1: "Zeytin",
      2: "Domates",
      3: "Soğan",
      4: "Turşu"
    },
    1: {
      0: "Mantar",
      1: "Zeytin",
      2: "Domates",
      3: "Soğan",
      4: "Turşu"
    }
},
```

2. Array

```
{
    0: {
      0: "Mantar",
      1: "Zeytin",
      2: "Domates"
    },
    1: {
      0: "Mantar",
      1: "Zeytin",
      2: "Domates",
      3: "Soğan",
      4: "Turşu"
    }
},
```

Comment: if you know they will always be same length. then just do a loop and use `array_diff()`

Comment: @ROOT I already know how to use it, but I don't know how to use it with foreach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [array\_diff() with multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays)