# What is the practical use of array_diff_uassoc?

Tags: php, arrays

`array_diff_assoc` and `array_diff_uassoc` both do the same thing (compute difference b/w array with additinal index check) the only difference is  the later one accpet a `callback`.

The difference is just callback, In which case you should prefer `array_diff_uassoc` instead of `array_diff_assoc`.

I want to understand that If the callback is going to do the same as below is every case then what is the use of `array_diff_uassoc`

```
function key_compare_func($a, $b)
{
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b)? 1:-1;
}
```

Comment: Did you ask a question in the title and then answer it in the question contents?

Comment: "Is that how we get ants Other Barry? Yes Other Barry, that is exactly how we get ants."

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I rephrased the question

Comment: the callback isnt going to be what you posted, and if it is, you are doing it wrong

Comment: @Ascherer: I just copied from manual page.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117058/what-is-the-difference-between-array-udiff-assoc-and-array-diff-uassoc

Comment: @Ascherer: Not the duplicate one. People you are very quick to close the question. Just understand the question I can understand the question and the question is still a good one. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The practical difference is that the user-defined function can be *anything* other than the default. *You define the callback yourself.*

Just because the documentation only gives a simple example doesn't mean that that is the only possibility. Here is a contrived example of a callback function you'd use tom compare elements in a multi-dimensional array:

```
function key_compare_func($a, $b) {
    if ($a['key']['subkey'] === $b['key']['subkey']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['key']['subkey'] > $b['key']['subkey'])? 1:-1;
}
```

**Edit:** PHP7 has spaceships!

```
function key_compare_func($a, $b) {
    return $a['key']['subkey'] <=> $b['key']['subkey']
}
```