# Find which keys of separate arrays intersect using a function

Tags: php, laravel

Ok so I have two arrays, one is an input array full of data like :

```
$array1 = ["_token" => "62d46d4h6dfh841df8h", "sku62" => "3e", "name62" => "meh", "sku61" => "3e", "name61" => "mah", "sku64" => "3e", "name64" => "moh"]
```

The other holds simply id's: `$array2 = [64, 74, 61]`

edit for clarity: `$array1` is a snippet of input from a post request i.e. `$array1 = $request->all();` The numbers present within the keys of this array are unique Id's appended on form generation to distinguish between rows with multiple form elements.

Each row has an "update" checkbox also with an appended unique id. When ticked this id shows up in the request e.g. update64.

`$array2` was populated by doing a foreach through the request, identifying the update string and isolating the id:

```
foreach ($array1 as $id => $value) {

     $idInt = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
     $str = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $id);

     if ($str === "update") {
         array_push($array2, $idInt);
     }
}
```

I want a solution that returns the elements from `$array1` that have the appended ids found in `$array2`.

My own attempt looks like this:

```
$relevant_keys = function($key1, $key2) {
            return ((preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $key1) === $key2)) ? 1 : -1;
        };

        $filtered = array_intersect_ukey($array1, array_flip($array2), $relevant_keys);
```

However `$filtered` is returning empty and if I `dd($key2)` within the function it's not even returning an element from `$array2`, I get something from `$array1` instead so this has left me confused.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The output should be the elements from array1 with keys and values preserved but only elements with keys containing numbers from `$array2`

Comment: @RyanVincent I've updated the question hopefully that clarifies it for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution to the exact problem you posted:

```php
$filtered = [];

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $key, $matches)) continue;

    if ( ! isset($matches[1]) || ! in_array($matches[1], $array2)) continue;

     $filtered[$key] = $value;
}
```

But I'm not sure you're approaching this correctly. That input looks suspicious.

Are you sure there's no better way to format the request?

Comment: Hi Joseph, cheers for the reply. That input is a snippet of the post request where I've done nothing more than `$array1 = $request->all();`
The id's are appended on form creation for each row.

Comment: I've added some context to the question. This solution doesn't actually preserve the keys from `$array1` which is what I need. I only wish to remove elements that do not have the attached ids specified in `$array2`.

Comment: I just changed `$filtered[$matches[1]] = $value` to `$filtered[$key] = $value`. Might make sense to adjust your answer to that now that I've clarified more in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few important insights to share based on your coding attempt.

1. `array_intersect_ukey()` *should be* the perfect function call for his task, but alas, it is not.  I'll tell you why.

   - `array_intersect_ukey()` suffers in the same way as `array_intersect_uassoc()` and `array_uintersect_uassoc()` because the internal algorithm will stop looking for additional qualifying keys after it encounters its first one.  I first came upon this reality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817582/2943403).
   - Also, the way that you've declared and used the custom function arguments (`$key1` and `$key2`) indicates that you believe `$key1` always relates to the first nominated array and `$key2` always relates to the second nominated array.  This is not true and I have seen many developers with this same false impression.  The truth is that under the hood, the two parameters fed into the custom function may come from either array.
2. For the reasons in #1, I'll recommend that you shift your focus to `array_filter()`.  By establishing a lookup array containing whitelisted keys and filtering on keys, you can swiftly filter your data.  Inside the callback, I am using `trim()` to remove the letters before the id number at the end.  This is just one way of isolating the whole number at the end of each key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V5Ym6))

```
$lookup = array_flip($array2);
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array1,
        fn($key) => isset($lookup[ltrim($key, 'a..z')]),
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'sku61' => '3e',
  'name61' => 'mah',
  'sku64' => '3e',
  'name64' => 'moh',
)
```