# Why does PHP array_diff work this way

Tags: php

I was trying to filter date from a form down to only what a user has changed, and started using `array_filter` as is it seemed to do exactly what I wanted. I tested a few forms and ran into this unexpected behavior. When the "new" value is 1, it is not detected by `array_diff`. Also unexpected when running this on 3v4l.org, was that the foreach loop was actually faster than `array_filter` while returning the expected result. I've read the [man-page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for the functions and understand that it does a string comparison, but all array values are strings to start with so I wouldn't expect it to be a type conversion issue.

I've solved my initial issue and will gladly use the faster foreach loop, but I am interested if anyone can explain why this works this way.

https://3v4l.org/1JggJ

```
<?php

$array_1 = [
    'id' => '42',
    'base_id' => '23',
    'role_id' => '1',
    'title' => 'Manage Account',
    'slug' => 'manage_account',
    'parent' => '31',
    'order' => '1',
    'visibility' => '1'
];
$array_2 = [
    'id' => '42',
    'base_id' => '23',
    'role_id' => '99999',
    'title' => 'Manage Account',
    'slug' => 'manage_account',
    'parent' => '31',
    'order' => '1',
    'visibility' => '1'
];

var_dump(array_diff($array_1, $array_2));
// Result (unexpected)
// array (size=0)
//   empty        

$diff = [];
foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
    if ((string) $array_1[$key] !== (string) $array_2[$key]) {
        $diff[$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($diff);
// Result (expected)
// array (size=1)
//   'role_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: FYI, `array_diff_assoc()` seems to work correctly.

Comment: the value "1" is in both arrays, if you change array 1 to have  `'role_id' => "99999"`, then you get what you expected

Comment: `array_diff()` only looks at the *values* in the arrays. As an example, when looking at the `role_id` (value: `1`) of the first array, the function can see equal values (in keys `order` and `visibility`) in the second array, so there's no difference.  On the other hand, `array_diff_assoc()` takes both the value *and key* into consideration. (e.g. [an example with your arrays](https://3v4l.org/MgKEX).)

Comment: You can also use `array_diff($array_2, $array_1)` To see the `99999`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver not if the changed value in `$array_2` appears anywhere in `$array_1`, for the same reason as above.

Comment: @salathe:  Well it doesn't in this case, that's why I said that.

Comment: A good read about [the different `array_*diff_*()` functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817582/2943403).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_diff()` looks for exact duplicates for each value of array 1 in array 2, ignoring the keys.

`1` has a duplicate in array 2, e.g. under key `order`. That's why it's not listed as difference.

Whether or not this behavior is optimal or obvious is debatable, but that's how it works.

---

If you change the `1` to a `3`, it will be reported, as array 2 does not contain a value `3`:

```
    $array_1 = [
        'id' => '42',
        'base_id' => '23',
        'role_id' => '3',
        'title' => 'Manage Account',
        'slug' => 'manage_account',
        'parent' => '31',
        'order' => '1',
        'visibility' => '1'
    ];
    $array_2 = [
        'id' => '42',
        'base_id' => '23',
        'role_id' => '99999',
        'title' => 'Manage Account',
        'slug' => 'manage_account',
        'parent' => '31',
        'order' => '1',
        'visibility' => '1'
    ];

    var_dump(array_diff($array_1, $array_2));
    // Result (unexpected)
    // array (size=1)
    //   'role_id' => string '3' (length=1)
```

---

If you want the keys to be taken into account, use `array_diff_assoc()` instead.

Comment: "for each key" **value** not key

Comment: typos happen :-)